# Updating Firebase Email and username in a single function with error handling in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a button where the current user can update their email and username.

My current function is

```
 func updateDetails(withEmail email: String, andDisplayName 
 displayName: String, updateComplete: @escaping(_ error: Error?) -> ()) {

        let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
        currentUser?.updateEmail(to: email, completion: { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                self.createError(title: "Error updating email", message: "\(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child((self.user?.uid)!).child("email")
                ref.setValue(Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)
        }
    })

        let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
        changeRequest?.displayName = displayName
        changeRequest?.commitChanges { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                self.createError(title: "Error updating display name", message: "\(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            } else {
                let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child((self.user?.uid)!).child("name")
                ref.setValue(Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName)
                self.welcomeLabel.text = "Hi, \(self.currentUserNameTextField.text ?? "")"
            }
        }

}
```

I am then calling this function when the button is pressed

```
@IBAction func saveChangesButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if emailTextField.text == nil || currentUserNameTextField.text == nil {
        createError(title: "Error", message: "Email and name fields must not be blank")
    } else {
        updateDetails(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, andDisplayName: currentUserNameTextField.text!) { (error) in
            if error == nil {
                self.createError(title: "Success", message: "")
            } else {
                self.createError(title: "Error", message: "\(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The details are updating in the authentication and database, however this bit of code is never being ran

```
 if error == nil {
                self.createError(title: "Success", message: "")
            } else {
                self.createError(title: "Error", message: "\(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }
```

Would anyone know why this is not being called?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the optional `error` isn't already initialized, thus not nil? Have you tried breaking execution there to check the value of `error`?

Answer (score 0):

While you're passing in a completion handler in your call to `updateDetails(withEmail email: String, andDisplayName displayName: String, updateComplete:)`, the implementation of that function is never calling `updateComplete:`. This doesn't happen automatically, but is something you will have to implement yourself.

Since you have two operations, Ill assume you only want to call the completion handler once both have completed. A simple way to implement that, is to make the two operations sequentially:

```
func updateDetails(withEmail email: String, andDisplayName 
 displayName: String, updateComplete: @escaping(_ error: Error?) -> ()) {
    let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
    currentUser?.updateEmail(to: email, completion: { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            self.createError(title: "Error updating email", message: "\(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion(error)
        } else {
            let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child((self.user?.uid)!).child("email")
            ref.setValue(Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)


            let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
            changeRequest?.displayName = displayName
            changeRequest?.commitChanges { (error) in
                if error != nil {
                    self.createError(title: "Error updating display name", message: "\(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                } else {
                    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child((self.user?.uid)!).child("name")
                    ref.setValue(Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName)
                    self.welcomeLabel.text = "Hi, \(self.currentUserNameTextField.text ?? "")"

                    completion()
                }
                else {
                    completion(error)
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Above we have two operations:

- First you update the user's email address.
- If that fails, the code calls the completion handler with the error.
- If the update succeeds, the code continues to update the user profile.
- If the update profile update fails, it calls the completion handler with the error.
- The the update succeeds, it calls the completion handler without any arguments to signal that it's done.

There is still a race condition in there, since the `ref.setValue(...)` could complete before the `changeRequest?.commitChanges`. If that is a concern for your use-case, you should also add a completion handler for the `ref.setValue(...)` and then call the `changeRequest?.commitChanges` from within that. So at that point you'll have three sequential operations.